# Detected type of solidity contract in Remix: TokenFactory example

Tags: solidity, remix

I am new to solidity and I am playing around with a sample "Factory Contracts" as 
 in this git:
https://gist.github.com/carolplay/b547d54f39c7d4d35f9a6aa71a1df1e3

I was able to deploy a Token contract, or deploy a TokenFactory contract.
But after calling the createToken method of the deployed TokenFactory, which is supposed to deploy a new Token contract, and I loaded the returned address, the recognized type is TokenFactory instead of Token in Remix.

I wonder if I messed up something or the remix IDE because this example is not that complicated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the token contract and the address of the token contract. In the way that you show, Remix believes that what is `at address` is the TokenFactory, because this is what you selected. Just select `Token` instead of `TokenFactory`.

hope this helps.

Comment: A bit duplicate answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the "At address" feature of Remix but I'd assume you have to state the type manually correctly. Your picture displays that you are loading a `TokenFactory` from the address and not a `Token`. Try changing the type (just above point 3)?

Anyway, for a beginner I would not recommend playing around with factory models. Start with basic token creations without factories and check out some cool tutorial such as CryptoZombies https://cryptozombies.io/ (I'm not affiliated with them).